# Display meta tag content as a string on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have the following code:

```
lblMetaTag.Text = 
   "<meta property='" + ctrl.property_name + 
       "' content='" + ctrl.property_value + "' />";
```

When it renders to the page - it renders the meta tag and not the string representation.

How do I display it as the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
lblMetaTag.Text = 
   "&lt ;meta property='" + ctrl.property_name + "' content='" + 
    ctrl.property_value + "' /&gt ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML encoding before sending putting it on your page.

Answer (score 0):

This this

```
lblMetaTag.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(
        "<meta property='" + ctrl.property_name + 
        "' content='" + ctrl.property_value + "' />");
```

Hope this helps.